# Turning an if statement to a false check

Tags: javascript, logic

I have a silly if statement that I cannot seem to reverse.. well you will see what I mean.

```
if (index == len_league - 1 && $(this).hasClass('highlight')){
     // dont do anything
    }else{
        $(this).delay(250*index).slideUp(550);  
    }
```

This doesn't work

```
if (index != len_league - 1 && $(this).hasClass('highlight') == false){
        $(this).delay(250*index).slideUp(550);  
    }
```

Comment: DeMorgan's Law states that you have to flip the logical operator inside. ~(P ^ Q) => ~P v ~Q

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to reverse the logical operator also

```
if (index != len_league - 1 || $(this).hasClass('highlight') == false){
        $(this).delay(250*index).slideUp(550);  
}
```

Comment: or better yet `if (index != len_league - 1 || !$(this).hasClass('highlight'))`

Comment: Thanks. I didn't consider altering the and/or!

Comment: @user3822370: You might want to have a look at De Morgan's laws: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws

Answer (score 1):

I think you can do this?

```
if(!(index == len_league - 1 && $(this).hasClass('highlight'))){
    $(this).delay(250*index).slideUp(550);  
}
```